# PHP - Seperate words into different categories?

Tags: php

Lets say I have a  text document that cannot be changed in any  way and needs to be left as is.

Example of what the text document is likely formatted  to  be:

```
1. What is soup commonly paired with?
2.
3.
4. Alcohol
5. Water
6. Bread
7. Vegtables
8.
9.
10.
```

Note:

The numbers are not included, but they are used to represent the small spaces in between the  words that are always there.

There is not always a question mark with the question

Note 2:

The question may be on 2 lines sometimes and may look like this below

```
0. What is soup 
1. commonly paired with?
    2.
    3.
    4. Alcohol
    5. Water
    6. Bread
    7. Vegtables
    8.
    9.
    10.
```

Other:

So how exactly do I seperate them, for example into an array?

So like $questions[] and $answers[]

**The main problem is that I have nothing to link the questions and answers to:
I can't guess the exact line they are on
And the question doesn't always have a question mark
So there is nothing I can really link it to?**

Comment: I edited my question a bit to explain what I am wanting to do a bit better

Comment: Are there always two blank lines between the question and its answers? Does each document contain only one question and its answers? Do any of the answers use more than one line? Does "small spaces in between the words" refer to the two blank lines, or did you mean there are spaces at the beginning of the lines?

Comment: I didn't  think of that one (There are 2 things I can be sure of. The question is always larger than the answer,  and just like you said, the answers never cover more than one line)

Comment: So how do I  grab them knowing that the answers only cover 1 line each (There can sometimes be up to 5 answers)

Comment: The blank lines are important. If there are always blank lines between the question and answers, you can split it that way. If not, it gets tricky.

Comment: I know  buddy that is my issue (They could be on any line, the questions could be 10 lines  down sometimes and there is no way of guessing)

Comment: It would be easy if they were always on the  same line

Comment: But is there always at least one blank line between the question and answers? It doesn't matter exactly how many, as long as there's one you can use that.

Comment: Yes, there will be a blank line always between the question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already read the text from the document into a variable `$text`, you can separate the question and answers by splitting on the first blank line in the text.

```
$qAndAs = preg_split('/\n\s*\n/', $text, 2, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The split pattern is a line break (`\n`), zero or more whitespaces (`\s*`), and another line break.

That should give you an two-element array, where `[0]` is the question and `[1]` is the answers.
If it doesn't, then something went wrong.

```
if (count($qAndAs) !== 2) {
    // The text from the document didn't fit the expected pattern.
    // Decide how to handle that. Maybe throw an exception.
}
```

After you have separated them, you can remove any new lines from the question

```
$question = str_replace(["\r", "\n"], ' ', trim($qAndAs[0]));
```

and split your answers into another array.

```
$answers = preg_split('/\s*\n\s*/', $qAndAs[1], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions accept multiple questions / answers in a single file.

**Solution 1** (similar to the other one in this thread):

```
$questions = array();
$answers = array();

//Split text into questions and answers blocks (2 line breaks or more from each other)
$text = preg_split('/\n{2,}/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach ($text as $key => $value)
{
    //0, 2, 4, ... are questions, 1, 3, 5, ... are answers
    if ($key % 2)
    {
        $answers[] = explode("\n", $value);
    }
    else
    {
        $questions[] = str_replace("\n", '', $value);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2** (ugly line by line reading from a file):

```
//Open the file
$f = fopen("test.txt","r");

//Initialize arrays of all questions and all answers
$all_questions = array();
$all_answers = array();

$is_question = true;
$last = ''; //contains a previous line

//Iterate over lines
while (true)
{
    //Get line
    $line = fgets($f);

    //Check if end of file
    $end = ($line === false);

    //Trim current line
    $line = trim($line);

    if ($line != '')
    {
        //If the previous line was empty, then reset current question and answers
        if ($last == '')
        {
            $question = array();
            $answers = array();
        }

        //Add line of question or answer
        if ($is_question)
        {
            $question[] = $line;
        }
        else
        {
            $answers[] = $line;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //If the previous line wasn't empty, or we reached the end of file, then save question / answers, and toggle $is_question
        if ($last != '' OR $end)
        {
            if ($is_question)
            {
                $all_questions[] = implode(' ', $question); //implode to merge multiline question
                $is_question = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $all_answers[] = $answers;
                $is_question = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //Break if end of file
    if ($end)
    {
        break;
    }

    $last = $line;
}

fclose($f);
```